# substring before function in XSLT 2.0

Tags: substring, xslt-2.0

I need help with string manipulation.

Scenario: 
`<ADR_LINE>This is a sample text, to test adr-line.</ADR_LINE>`

Requirement is to split ADR_LINE into 2 if length is more than 20. While splitting we need to make sure that the last character in the string should be space, comma, or full stop.

In this example, total length is 40 and split is something like: 
`<ADR_LINE>This is a sample tex</ADR_LINE>`
 `<ADR_LINE>t, to test adr-line.</ADR_LINE>`

To avoid cutting word 'text' in this example, I am trying to use below logic: 
`<xsl:if test="not(substring($adrlnpart1, 20) = '  ' or '.' or ',' or '-')">`
`<xsl:variable name="adrln2trunc" select="substring-before($adrln2part1,' ')"/>`
`</xsl:if>`

in the substring-before function, I am not sure if we can specify multiple characters (space, comma, or full stop) to look at the end of string. In this example checking for space may work, but other scenarios will require comma or full stop.

Please suggest your ideas to handle this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general I think that `xsl:analyze-string` in XSLT 2 is a better tool for a task like this but your requirement is not clear to me, what happens if there are more than 40 characters, do you want to split into more than two parts?

Comment: @Martin thanks. if length of string is more than 40 characters then it will be split into 3 ADR_LINE. Also, ADR_LINE cannot exceed length of 20 characters, so expected output is:   'This is a sample' in first ADR_LINE, 'text, to test' in another and 'adr-line' in last address line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using `xsl:analyze-string`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ADR_LINE[string-length() > 20]">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex=".{{19,}}?([., ]|$)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <ADR_LINE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </ADR_LINE>                
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <ADR_LINE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </ADR_LINE>                   
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Splits

```
<ADR_LINE>This is a sample text, to test adr-line.</ADR_LINE>
```

into

```
<ADR_LINE>This is a sample text,</ADR_LINE>
<ADR_LINE> to test adr-line.</ADR_LINE>
```

Online sample at http://xsltransform.net/pNmBy2a.